# Is sevlets a valid tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Today I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21153309/1) about servlets (now I have edited it), which was tagged with [sevlets](/questions/tagged/sevlets), so I checked its [tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sevlets/info) but couldn't find more information(*currently it holds 22 questions*).  It seems like a wrong tag, which needs to be replaced with [servlets](/questions/tagged/servlets).

Please do the needful.

Comment: That's...an impressive number of questions with a misspelled tag actually. Good to see it's taken care of.